# Magento 2.2.1 "Notice: Undefined index: src in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Generator/Head.php on line 125"

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.2.1

I've got a problem with Magento 2.2.1 after updating from 2.0.1. The backend still works at /admin but accessing any page on the frontend produces this error:

Notice: Undefined index: src in /home/snackxpr/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Generator/Head.php on line 125

I've tried the following with no luck:

1. Change to developer mode
2. Change to production mode
3. Clear Magento cache from admin
4. Clear cache, page_cache, and generation folders' contents
5. Verify permissions on all Magento files
6. Deploy static content

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, but can't seem to get the site to work on the frontend anymore.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue??Please answer me because i have same issue..:(

Comment: @ChiCgi I have the same issue. Please post if you have found the solution

Comment: Look a lot like https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11224 : something may be wrong in a third-party module, one of your page content heading...